# the correct use of max(), min() function in python

Tags: python, max, min

im strugguling to get a solution for my problem. I keep getting errors with my max(), and min() function.

Im trying to write a code that takes user inputs until a negative value is inputted.Then i need to take the sum, highest, lowest and avarges of the numbers.

the code:

```
print("Please enter values(negative value to stop)")
g=1
flag=0

list = []

while not flag:
    val=float(input("Enter value number "+str(g)+ ": "))
    g+=1
    if val<0:
        flag=1
    else:
            sum+=val
print("Sum of "+str(g-2)+ " values: "+str(sum))




print("The highest number is: ",min(low_number))
print("The lowest number is: ",min(low_number))
print("The average number is: ",sum/(g-1))
```

Comment: You never update `low_number`, why do you expect it to have a min and a max?

Comment: "I keep getting errors with..." _So what are the errors?_ Saying "I'm getting an error" isn't very helpful. Please _always_ include exact error messages, line numbers, and tracebacks when asking questions. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

low_number is empty, so min() on an empty list will fail.

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
print("Please enter values(negative value to stop)")
flag=0
values=[]
while not flag:
    val=float(input("Enter value number : "))
    if val < 0:
        break
    values.append(val)

print("Sum of values: ",sum(values))

print("The highest number is: ",max(values))
print("The lowest number is: ",min(values))
print("The average number is: ",sum(values)/len(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert but I think it is because you are not entering any of the values inputted into the lists. There is no where that you are appending the given values so there are no numbers in the lists to be checked.

I have not tested this but perhaps try

```
 print("Please enter values(negative value to stop)")
 flag=0
 number = []
 while not flag:
     val=float(input("Enter value number :"))
     if val<0:
         flag=1
     else:
        number.append(val)
        
 print("Sum of "+str(len(number))+ " values: "sum(number))




 print("The highest number is: ",max(number))
 print("The lowest number is: ",min(number))
 print("The average number is: ",sum(number)/len(number))
```

EDIT: I made some changes to ensure it all works :)

EDIT 2: I have tested this and this code works entirely